# YII 2.0 REST API error handler

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How to set a REST API error handler, when API used as a module.
I'm getting an invalid 404 found exception in HTML response rather than a json/xml response.

this is the sample api URL with an invalid entry point

**http://localhost.backend.com/api/v1/invalidentrypoint**

here api is in a module and v1 in nested with api module.

the reponse is

**Not Found (#404)
Unable to resolve the request "api/v1/invalidentrypoint".
The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.**

I'm expecting a response like

**HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 05:31:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.20 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
    "type": "yii\web\NotFoundHttpException",
    "name": "Not Found Exception",
    "message": "The requested resource was not found.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 404
}**

please help.

Comment: I don't know how, but it gives you in json format if you did the request from a rest client, not a browser

Comment: no, I've already tried it. may be a problem relating to modules that i've configured.
I'm getting full HTML as response!

Comment: Do you use custom errorHandler? I had similar issue when i was registring handler in module. But after moveing it into config->components it worked like expected.

Comment: we have the same problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried setting the response format to json?

just add to the config:

```
'response' => [
    'format' =>  \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON
]
```

here's some info from the yii documentation:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-error-handling.md

Edit: using the yii define from ethan's comment
the define is "json" but it's a good pratice to use the defined const from Yii

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.  Though, probably, it would be better to set the format to \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON rather than the raw string, 'json'.

Comment: Does this not set the format for all responses? Good if Yii is only serving JSON. What if you have HTML pages and an API?

Answer (score 0):

I add the following to the constructor of my API Controller(s):

`public function __construct(string $id, Module $module, array $config = [])
{
    parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
    \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
}`

This allows me to specify JSON error responses for individual controllers.